# Adding accessors to Class::XSAccessor via predefined hash?

Tags: perl, hash, accessor

Consider the following example:

```
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;

{
  package MyTestPck;
  use Data::Dumper;
  use Tie::IxHash;
  sub ordered_hash { # http://stackoverflow.com/a/3001400/277826
    tie my %hash => 'Tie::IxHash';
    %hash = @_;
    \%hash
  }
  my $fields = ordered_hash(
          (map { $_ => $_ } (qw(
          varA
          varB
          varC
          )))
    );
  print Dumper($fields);
  use Class::XSAccessor
      accessors => {
        %{$fields}
      };
  sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my @set_arr = @_; # the rest
    my $ic = 0; my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    for my $k (keys %{$fields}) {
      my $fld = $fields->{$k};
      my $val = $set_arr[$ic];
      print("k $k fld $fld ic/val $ic $val\n");
      $self->$fld($val);
      $ic++;
    }
    return $self;
  }
  1;
}

my $pcktestobj = MyTestPck->new((10, 20, 30));
print Dumper($pcktestobj);
```

If I run it as is; the code fails with:

```
$ perl /tmp/test.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'varA' => 'varA',
          'varB' => 'varB',
          'varC' => 'varC'
        };
k varA fld varA ic/val 0 10
Can't locate object method "varA" via package "MyTestPck" at /tmp/test.pl line 34.
```

However, if you replace the middle part of the code with:

```
...
  use Class::XSAccessor
      accessors => ordered_hash(
          (map { $_ => $_ } (qw(
          varA
          varB
          varC
          )))
    );
...
```

... then the output is as expected:

```
$ perl /tmp/test.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'varA' => 'varA',
          'varB' => 'varB',
          'varC' => 'varC'
        };
k varA fld varA ic/val 0 10
k varB fld varB ic/val 1 20
k varC fld varC ic/val 2 30
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'varC' => 30,
                 'varB' => 20,
                 'varA' => 10
               }, 'MyTestPck' );
```

So, apparently, I cannot set accessors via predefined hash, as in `use Class::XSAccessor accessors => { %{$fields} };` - I apparently must specify the accessors hash inline.

But why is this? Is there anything in the [Class::XSAccessor docs](https://metacpan.org/source/SMUELLER/Class-XSAccessor-1.19/README) that should have alerted me to this behavior? Is there a way I could use predefined fields (as I intended in the first example) with `Class::XSAccessor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use` statements are executed at **compile time**, but your hash doesn't get populated until **run time**. Look at this example:

```
my $x = {};        # this statement is executed **SECOND**
use strict;        # this statement is executed **FIRST**
```

So you couldn't usefully employ the `$x` variable in the `use` statement above. `$x` would not have been defined yet.

Luckily, `use` statements can easily be broken down into a `require` followed by an `import`. Each of those happen at run time. So try replacing this:

```
use Class::XSAccessor
   accessors => {
      %{$fields}
   };
```

With this:

```
require Class::XSAccessor;
Class::XSAccessor->import( accessors => $fields );
```

---

An alternative would be to force `$fields` to be populated at compile time. This should work, but is less pretty:

```
my $fields;
BEGIN {
    $fields = ordered_hash(
            (map { $_ => $_ } (qw(
            varA
            varB
            varC
        )))
      );
    print Dumper($fields);
};
use Class::XSAccessor
    accessors => {
      %{$fields}
    };
```

Comment: Many thanks, @tobyink - wasn't aware of the execution order of `use` statements; awesome tip with the `require` and the `BEGIN` !! Cheers!

Comment: It might be worth trying to understand how the [begincheck.pl](https://github.com/alanqian/test/blob/master/perl/begincheck.pl) script works. It looks confusing at first, but once it "clicks" in your mind, you'll never be tripped up by run-time versus compile-time again.